# Connecting to Peachtree database using php?

Tags: php, odbc, pervasive-sql

Iam developing an application in php which can fetch transaction,invoices.etc from peachtree database. So for database access I selected ODBC method by connecting using Pervasive SQL. 
I used connection string like this:-

```
$connection = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};Dbq=C:\Sagepro\Peachtree\Company\Sample\PAW\BCS","Peachtree","password");
```

But it is giving error

```
 ( ! ) Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Data Record Manager]Cannot locate the named database you specified(Btrieve Error 2301), SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\peachtreeapi\index.php on line 2
```

How to rectify this??

Comment: Appreciate this is old and you have your answer so I'm not supplying as an answer but perhaps the string connection you attempted above fails because you needed to escape backslashes `$connection = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};Dbq=C:\\Sagepro\\Peachtree\\Company\\Sample\\PAW\\BCS","Peachtree","password");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this connection string.. it will work

```
 $connect=odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=DSNname;","Username","Password",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this connection string  will work:-

```
 $dbhandle = odbc_connect("DSN=YOURDSN;DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};DATAPATH=c:\peachw\YOURCOMPANY;DDFPATH=c:\peachw\YOURCOMPANY","username","password");
```

username & password is the details you provided in peachtree -> maintain->users->setupsecurity->data access/crystalreport ->All option in your peachtree app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a Pervasive Database Name pointing to your data location.  You can't specify a path in the connection string. Pervasive removed that functionality.  Once you create the Database Name through the Pervasive Control Center, you would specify that name in your connection string:

```
$connection = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};Dbq=XXXXXXXX","Peachtree","password");
```

where "XXXXXXXX" is the name of the database you created in the PErvasive Control Center.

Comment: I used your code but that also doesnt work. Can you provide more information about this.still its giving error like :-                     Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Data Record Manager]Cannot locate the named database you specified(Btrieve Error 2301), SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\peachtreeapi\index.php on line 2

Comment: Did you create a Database Name?  Did you change the connection string Dbq= parameter to match the name you created?  I edited my answer to be a little clearer on the naming.

Comment: Yes, I created a db name called SageConnect and placed here.. but its getting error. Did I need to do any other thing  for connection ??